# How to undo a git push on the wrong branch

Tags: git

I made changes to several files, committed and pushed them to the master only to realize I was on the wrong branch for the commits and push.  How can I undo this?  I am not sure if git reset will give me what I want.

Comment: for easier convenienve. let's say you have a branch A. Did you commit stuff on master and pushed to master on the remote repo? So your branch A actually doesn't have anything and you want your stuff on that branch and revert master to what it was?

Comment: Since branches are just pointers to commits, you can change these pointers to point to whatever commits you want. You might need to use `reset` and `merge --ff-only` to keep your tree intact.

Answer (score 4):

To avoid having to rewrite the history you can use [git revert](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert).

This will create a new commit that is the inverse of the commit you accidentally pushed.

Find the sha's of the commits you pushed and run this command for each sha:

```
git revert <sha>
```

Then push your revert commits.

Comment: I did 'git revert' just now and it seems to be exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks for posting this!  I've had a lot of trouble keeping my files going to the right branches and this was just what I've needed.